# Did Bhimasena laugh at Duryodhana infront of Vasudeva?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, duryodhana

It is known that Bhimasena laughed at Duryodhana in Mayasabha due to the incident of Duryodhana falling down due to confusion.

Did it happen in front of Sri Krishna?

The following passage from [Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm) of the Mahabharata confirms that it happened in front of Lord Krishna

> Yudhishthira, after having, through the wise counsels of Vasudeva and
> by the valour of Bhimasena and Arjuna, slain Jarasandha (the king of
> Magadha) and the proud Chaidya, acquired the right to perform the
> grand sacrifice of Rajasuya abounding in provisions and offering and
> fraught with transcendent merits. And Duryodhana came to this
> sacrifice; and when he beheld the vast wealth of the Pandavas
> scattered all around, the offerings, the precious stones, gold and
> jewels; the wealth in cows, elephants, and horses; the curious
> textures, garments, and mantles; the precious shawls and furs and
> carpets made of the skin of the Ranku; he was filled with envy and
> became exceedingly displeased. And when he beheld the hall of assembly
> elegantly constructed by Maya (the Asura architect) after the fashion
> of a celestial court, he was inflamed with rage. **And having started in
> confusion at certain architectural deceptions within this building, he
> was derided by Bhimasena in the presence of Vasudeva, like one of mean
> descent.**

But in Sabha Parva of Mahabharatha, the incident happened in the absence of Krishna (After Krishna went to Dwaraka after Rajasuya).

> "After all the Kings and the Brahmanas had gone away, the powerful
> **Vasudeva addressing Yudhishthira said**,--'O son of the Kuru race, with
> thy leave, **I also desire to go to Dwaraka**. By great good fortune, thou
> hast accomplished the foremost of sacrifices--Rajasuya!' Thus
> addressed by Janarddana, Yudhishthira replied, 'Owing to thy grace, O
> Govinda. I have accomplished the great sacrifice. And it is owing to
> thy grace that the whole Kshatriya world having accepted my sway, had
> come hither with valuable tribute. O hero, without thee, my heart
> never feeleth any delight. How can I, therefore, O hero, give thee, O
> sinless one, leave to go? But thou must have to go to the city of
> Dwaraka.' The virtuous Hari of worldwide fame, thus addressed by
> Yudhishthira, cheerfully went with his cousin to Pritha and said,--'O
> aunt, thy sons have now obtained the imperial dignity. They have
> obtained vast wealth and been also crowned with success. Be pleased
> with all this. Commanded by thee, O aunt, I desire to go to Dwaraka.'
> After this, Kesava bade farewell to Draupadi and Subhadra. Coming out
> then of the inner apartments accompanied by Yudhishthira, he performed
> his ablutions and went through the daily rites of worship, and then
> made the Brahmanas utter benedictions. Then the mighty armed Daruka
> came there with a car of excellent design and body resembling the
> clouds. And beholding that Garuda-bannered car arrived thither, the
> high-souled one, with eyes like lotus leaves, walked round it
> respectfully and ascending on it set out for Dwaravati. And king
> Yudhishthira the just, blessed with prosperity, accompanied by his
> brothers, followed on foot the mighty Vasudeva. Then Hari with eyes
> like lotus leaves, stopping that best of cars for a moment, addressing
> Yudhishthira the son of Kunti, said,--'O king of kings, cherishest
> thou thy subjects with ceaseless vigilance and patience. And as the
> clouds are unto all creatures, as the large tree of spreading bough is
> unto birds, as he of a thousand eyes is unto the immortals, be thou
> the refuge and support of thy relatives. **And Krishna and Yudhishthira
> having thus talked unto each other took each other's leave and
> returned to their respective homes.** And, O king, after the chief of
> the Satwata race had gone to Dwaravati, **king Duryodhana alone, with
> king Suvala's son, Sakuni,--these bulls among men,--continued to live
> in that celestial assembly house.**
>
> [[Section 44, Sisupala-badha Parva, Sabha Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02046.htm)

and also the same Parva tells that Bhima and Arjuna laughed.

> Vaisampayana said,--"That bull among men, Duryodhana, continued to
> dwell in that, assembly house (of the Pandavas). And with Sakuni, the
> Kuru prince slowly examined the whole of that mansion, and the Kuru
> prince beheld in it many celestial designs, which he had never seen
> before in the city called after the elephant (Hastinapore). And one
> day king Duryodhana in going round that mansion came upon a crystal
> surface. And the king, from ignorance, mistaking it for a pool of
> water, drew up his clothes. And afterwards finding out his mistake the
> king wandered about the mansion in great sorrow. And sometime after,
> the king, mistaking a lake of crystal water adorned with lotuses of
> crystal petals for land, fell into it with all his clothes on.
> Beholding Duryodhana fallen into the lake, **the mighty Bhima laughed
> aloud as also the menials of the palace.** And the servants, at the
> command of the king, soon brought him dry and handsome clothes.
> Beholding the plight of Duryodhana, **the mighty Bhima and Arjuna and
> both the twins--all laughed aloud.** Being unused to putting up with
> insults, Duryodhana could not bear that laugh of theirs. Concealing
> his emotions he even did not cast his looks on them. And beholding the
> monarch once more draw up his clothes to cross a piece of dry land
> which he had mistaken for water, they all laughed again. And the king
> sometime after mistook a closed door made of crystal as open. And as
> he was about to pass through it his head struck against it, and he
> stood with his brain reeling. And mistaking as closed another door
> made of crystal that was really open, the king in attempting to open
> it with stretched hands, tumbled down. And coming upon another door
> that was really open, the king thinking it as closed, went away from
> it. And, O monarch, king Duryodhana beholding that vast wealth in the
> Rajasuya sacrifice and having become the victim of those numerous
> errors within the assembly house at last returned, with the leave of
> the Pandavas, to Hastinapore.
>
> [[Section 46, Sisupala-badha Parva, Sabha Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02046.htm)

Which one is true? Is the word Vasudeva in Adiparva the wrong translation and does it refers to Arjuna, whose name is also Krishna?

Comment: The original Bharata says Krishna is there. What are other sources you have heard other version?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma preachers told that it happened after Krishna went to Dwaraka, I will update it soon...

Comment: It seems that first krishna and droupathi laughed and then they looked bhima bhima laughed with their company so krishna was there the whole incident was instigated sri krishna to increase the hatred of duryidhana he was kept incharge wealth handling department by srikrishna to increase duryodhana asuya envy

Comment: @PrasannaR The second quote clearly says that Krishna is not there when the incident is happening. He left once Rajasuya completed.

Comment: second quote just summarizes the various  events " having become the victim of those numerous errors" it didnt mention timing. it all happened one during rajasuya while entering the ygna hall.  another during presence krishna

Comment: @PrasannaR Please read the section, it happened after Rajasuya only.